# Issue while redirecting multiprocessing output to single output file

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, output, python-multiprocessing

I am facing issue while redirecting multiprocessing output to single output file. If any process from multiprocessing taking longer time to complete then its output is overlapping with other process's output in output file. instead of appending output to next line its printing multiple output on same line.

It should append every process output on new different line in output file.

Comment: Sounds like you are truncating the file rather than appending it. We'll need to see the actual code you are working with to provide any real help

Comment: If you have multiple processes writing (appending?) to the same file, you need to exert control over that file (e.g., with a lock) to ensure that no more than one process is accessing it at any given point in time.

Comment: I am redirecting command1 >> output.txt, command2 >> output.txt in the multiprocessing. 

output_list.append(command)
count += 1
with Pool(len(output_list)) as p:
p.map(multiprocess_batch, output_list)

Comment: @CoderMe Show your code and I'm sure someone will be able to suggest a solution. If you're running processes with shell level redirection then you're doing it wrong

Comment: I want that more than one process can access and append same output file at same time. but it should not overlap its output.

Comment: Can multiple processes access and append same output file at same time without overlapping?

Comment: @CoderMe No they can't. Depending on timing you may or may not see overlaps but, in principle, the approach is wrong. We're going to need to see your code